# Error displaying an error message to the user

Tags: bug, answers, android-app

I got an error as below in the screenshot.

[image]

**How to reproduce:**

1. Click <kbd>**Post to answer**</kbd> for any question.
2. Within the `TextBlock`, leave about 30 spaces and press on <kbd>PREVIEW</kbd> / <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd>.  For first time it will not render anything and on second press you will find the above error (*a kind of notification*).

Then you will get an message like

```
Body must be atleast 30 characters; you entered 0
```

Whereas this is not the behavior in <kbd>**Ask a question**</kbd>, it will simply show a notification like  "Please enter a question".

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.82 (beta). The app only shown the message "*Please fix the following: Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0*" without the Crouton error message.